# No error but something is wrong with DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I roughly translated vb.net code to c# for a simple POS system i'm coding for school. But when i try to add things to the datagrid using button click event there is no change in the datagrid. there are no errors. the datagrid is not connected to a database, at least not yet.

here's the code where i insert things to the datagrid:

```
private void txtAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtProduct.Text) & !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtQuantity.Text) & !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPrice.Text))
    {
        var with = dataSales;

        int ii = 0;
        int orderproduct = 0;
        int count = 0;
        for (ii = 0; ii <= with.RowCount - 1; ii++)
        {
            if (txtProduct.Text == Convert.ToString(dataSales[0, ii].Value))
            {
                count = count + 1;
                if (count != 0)
                {
                    orderproduct = Convert.ToInt32(dataSales[2, ii].Value) + Convert.ToInt32(txtQuantity.Text);

                    dataSales[2, ii].Value = orderproduct;
                    dataSales[3, ii].Value = Convert.ToInt32(dataSales[2, ii].Value) * Convert.ToInt32(dataSales[1, ii].Value);

                }

                else
                {
                    if (count == 0)
                    {
                        float sum = Convert.ToInt32(txtPrice.Text) * Convert.ToInt32(txtQuantity.Text);
                        dataSales.Rows.Add(txtProduct.Text, txtPrice.Text, txtQuantity.Text, sum);
                        count = 0;
                    }

                    txtProduct.Clear();
                    txtQuantity.Clear();
                    txtPrice.Clear();

                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Nothing is Selected", "Error");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging?  That should reveal your logic error quickly.

Comment: what do you mean by debugging? sorry i'm still new to this.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sc65sadd.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Follow your counter and you will understand why you never get anything added. You start with 0 but add +1 every single time there is text to add. PUt it in debug and watch.

EDITED: Due to your comment you do not know how to debug. Open the .cs file in Visual Studio, Click on the left margin for the line that tests for text in the fields (the line below):

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtProduct.Text) & !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtQuantity.Text) & !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPrice.Text))
```

Now start the program, enter text and run it. It will stop on that line. You can then hit F11 and it will go to the line that increments the counter. This means you will always run this branch.

```
            if (count != 0)
            {
                orderproduct = Convert.ToInt32(dataSales[2, ii].Value) + Convert.ToInt32(txtQuantity.Text);

                dataSales[2, ii].Value = orderproduct;
                dataSales[3, ii].Value = Convert.ToInt32(dataSales[2, ii].Value) * Convert.ToInt32(dataSales[1, ii].Value);

            }
```

NOTE: You do not need this:

```
if (count == 0)
{
}
```

Why? You have already sent anything not 0 to the other branch. The else is sufficient at this point, and no need to waste a cycle determining if something that will ALWAYS be zero is zero